# InnoSetup is not restarting the closed applications

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, inno-setup, winforms-interop

I am working on an installer by using InnoSetup 5.5.6. Application is an CLR Windows forms application compiled with VS2013. Installer and application works succesfully. However, I wanted to check the behaviour of the installer when the APP is running. As mentioned in innosetup documentation installer warns user about the running application and says that it will close it and attempt to restart it.
It closes the application succesfully and completes the installation but the application is not restarted!

I tried /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS argument already but has no effect!

Any suggestions or hints that I can follow?

Here is the log:

```
2015-09-30 16:12:22.711   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+03:00)
2015-09-30 16:12:22.711   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.6 (a)
2015-09-30 16:12:22.711   Original Setup EXE: D:\Software Development\projects\tools\online updater\Setup\setup_OnlineUpdater.exe
2015-09-30 16:12:22.711   Setup command line: /SL5="$3D0374,14051236,422400,D:\Software Development\projects\tools\online updater\Setup\setup_OnlineUpdater.exe" /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /LOG="C:\log.txt"
2015-09-30 16:12:22.711   Windows version: 6.1.7601 SP1  (NT platform: Yes)
2015-09-30 16:12:22.711   64-bit Windows: Yes
2015-09-30 16:12:22.711   Processor architecture: x64
2015-09-30 16:12:22.711   User privileges: Administrative
2015-09-30 16:12:22.711   64-bit install mode: Yes
2015-09-30 16:12:24.027   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\sozmen\AppData\Local\Temp\is-79DG1.tmp
2015-09-30 16:12:32.506   RestartManager found an application using one of our files: Online Updater
2015-09-30 16:12:32.506   Can use RestartManager to avoid reboot? Yes (0)
2015-09-30 16:12:33.574   Starting the installation process.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.577   Shutting down applications using our files.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.624   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files\XXX\Online Updater\uninstall
2015-09-30 16:12:33.624   Will append to existing uninstall log: C:\Program Files\XXX\Online Updater\uninstall\unins000.dat
2015-09-30 16:12:33.627   -- File entry --
2015-09-30 16:12:33.627   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\XXX\Online Updater\uninstall\unins000.exe
2015-09-30 16:12:33.627   Non-default bitness: 32-bit
2015-09-30 16:12:33.629   Time stamp of our file: 2015-09-30 16:12:22.598
2015-09-30 16:12:33.629   Dest file exists.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.629   Time stamp of existing file: 2015-09-30 16:10:18.333
2015-09-30 16:12:33.629   Version of our file: 51.52.0.0
2015-09-30 16:12:33.629   Version of existing file: 51.52.0.0
2015-09-30 16:12:33.629   Installing the file.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.634   Uninstaller requires administrator: Yes
2015-09-30 16:12:33.639   Leaving temporary file in place for now.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.639   -- File entry --
2015-09-30 16:12:33.640   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\XXX\Online Updater\change.log
2015-09-30 16:12:33.640   Time stamp of our file: 2015-09-17 17:22:28.000
2015-09-30 16:12:33.640   Dest file exists.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.640   Time stamp of existing file: 2015-09-17 17:22:28.000
2015-09-30 16:12:33.640   Version of our file: (none)
2015-09-30 16:12:33.640   Version of existing file: (none)
2015-09-30 16:12:33.640   Installing the file.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.644   Successfully installed the file.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.644   -- File entry --
2015-09-30 16:12:33.644   Dest filename: C:\Users\sozmen\AppData\Local\XXX\applications.xml
2015-09-30 16:12:33.645   Time stamp of our file: 2015-09-30 12:34:22.000
2015-09-30 16:12:33.645   Dest file exists.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.645   Time stamp of existing file: 2015-09-30 12:34:22.000
2015-09-30 16:12:33.645   Version of our file: (none)
2015-09-30 16:12:33.645   Version of existing file: (none)
2015-09-30 16:12:33.645   Installing the file.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.647   Successfully installed the file.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.648   -- File entry --
2015-09-30 16:12:33.648   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\XXX\Online Updater\OnlineUpdater.exe
2015-09-30 16:12:33.648   Time stamp of our file: 2015-09-30 15:58:12.000
2015-09-30 16:12:33.648   Dest file exists.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.648   Time stamp of existing file: 2015-09-30 15:58:12.000
2015-09-30 16:12:33.648   Version of our file: 1.0.4489.23
2015-09-30 16:12:33.649   Version of existing file: 1.0.4489.23
2015-09-30 16:12:33.649   Same version. Skipping.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.649   -- Icon entry --
2015-09-30 16:12:33.650   Dest filename: C:\Users\Public\Desktop\XXX Online Updater.lnk
2015-09-30 16:12:33.650   Creating the icon.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.662   Successfully created the icon.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.743   Installation process succeeded.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.744   Attempting to restart applications.
2015-09-30 16:12:33.800   Need to restart Windows? No
2015-09-30 16:12:36.118   Deinitializing Setup.
2015-09-30 16:12:36.125   Log closed.
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl added the log file

Comment: Did the app use RegisterApplicationRestart?

Comment: @Martin: The docs I'v seen say this "Note: For Setup to be able to restart an application after the installation has completed, the application needs to be using the Windows RegisterApplicationRestart API function."

Comment: @PhilDW Sure, you are correct. Sorry, I've overlooked this.